# Nginx Config issue

Tags: debug

I keep getting the error message below and using `docker compose up`

```
open() "/etc/nginx/craftcms/security.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:16
```

Nginx Dockerfile (per github documentation):
`FROM craftcms/php-fpm:8.0.2`